# Not able understand the out put of the following program

Tags: java

```
class Test1{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "A\141B";
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

O/P : AaB

```
class Test2{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str = "A\659B";
        System.out.println(str);
    }

}
```

O/P : A59B

can any one please explain me the logic.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've been a member for almost a year... surely you know how to format posted code, right?

Comment: You need to learn about the string literal and ascii table http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the JLS - see Section [3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

The second example is slightly tricky.  The String escape `\65` gives 65 octal == `\u0035` == `'5'` in Unicode (or ASCII).

However, if you work both examples through methodical, the meaning will become clear to you.